# how to associate two tables and query by id in graphql

Tags: graphql

I have two tables product1 and product2, need to retrieve record by mfgcode which exists in both tables

newbie in graphql any help will be appreicated, tried few things but no luck doing so

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
    product1: () => product1,
    product2: () => product2
    },
}
```

need to get single record if same mfgcode in both tables matches

Comment: here is product1 and product2 tables
const product1 = [
    {
        "productmodel": "phone",
        "mfgcode": "185697621176850",
        "imei": 185697621176850,
        "manufacturer": "xxx",
        "productmodel": "Alpha",
    }
];
const product2 = [

    {
        "mfgCode": "151824762596608",
        "imei": 151824762596608,
        "interface": "all"
    },
    {
        "mfgCode": "185697621176850",
        "imei": 185697621176850,
        "interface": "all"
    }
];

Comment: const typeDefs = gql`
    type Product1Device {
    mfgcode: String
    imei: String
    manufacturer: String
    productmodel: String
    core: [Product2Device!]!

    }
    type Product2Device {
    mfgCode: String
    imei: String
    interface: String
    provider: [Product1Device!]!

    }

    type Query {
    product1: [Product1Device]
    product2: [Product2Device]
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
    product1: () => product1,
    product2: () => product2
    },
};